# Data Frame- Add number of occurrences with a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm having a bit of a struggle trying to figure out how to do the following. I want to map how many days of high sales I have previously a change of price. For example, I have a price change on day 10 and the high sales indicator will tell me any sale greater than or equal to 10. Need my algorithm to count the number of consecutive high sales.

In this case it should return 5 (day 5 to 9)

For example purposes, the dataframe is called `df`. Code:

```
#trying to create a while loop that will check if lag(high_sales) is 1, if yes it will count until
#there's a lag(high_sales) ==0

#loop is just my dummy variable that will take me out of the while loop
count_sales<-0
loop<-0
df<- df %>% mutate(consec_high_days= ifelse(price_change > 0, while(loop==0){
                                       if(lag(High_sales_ind)==1){
                                           count_sales<-count_sales +1}
                                       else{loop<-0}
                                       count_sales},0))
```

| day | price | price_change | sales | High_sales_ind |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| 6 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 1 |
| 8 | 5 | 0 | 12 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 0 | 14 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 11 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

This is my error message:

> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` column `consec_high_days`.
> i `consec_high_days = ifelse(...)`.
> i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

> Warning: Problem with `mutate()` column `consec_high_days`.
> i `consec_high_days = ifelse(...)`.
> i 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `consec_high_days`.
> i `consec_high_days = ifelse(...)`.
> x replacement has length zero

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very inelegant brute-force answer, though hopefully someone better than me can provide a more elegant answer - but to get the desired dataset, you can try:

```
df <- read.table(text = "day    price   price_change    sales   High_sales_ind
1 5 0   12  1
2   5   0   6   0
3   5   0   5   0
4   5   0   4   0
5   5   0   10  1
6   5   0   10  1
7   5   0   10  1
8   5   0   12  1
9   5   0   14  1
10  7   2   3   0
11  7   0   2   0", header = TRUE)

# assign consecutive instances of value
df$seq <- sequence(rle(as.character(df$sales >= 10))$lengths)

# Find how many instance of consecutive days occurred before price change
df <- df %>% mutate(lseq = lag(seq))

# define rows you want to keep and when to end
keepz <- df[df$price_change != 0, "lseq"]
end <- as.numeric(rownames(df[df$price_change != 0,]))-1

df_want <- df[keepz:end,-c(6:7)]
```

Output:

```
#     day price price_change sales High_sales_ind
# 5   5     5            0    10              1
# 6   6     5            0    10              1
# 7   7     5            0    10              1
# 8   8     5            0    12              1
# 9   9     5            0    14              1
```

Comment: It does work, however, I do believe there should be a more efficient way of doing it. Currently investigating.

Comment: Yea I wish I could be more help - though since there were no other answers I figured **something** was better than nothing. Great question, though, and I will be interested to see how it is solved. Please post your answer if you figure out a better way!